# How to add a multiple value in a single list HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<User>> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<User>>();

Tags: java

```
 HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<User>> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<User>>();
```

now that Integer is suppose 101 and for that my array list values in [jan,10,200,city]. so that if i displaying my list it will be like

```
101 :[jan,10,200,city].
```

if i adding another it will be like

```
101 :[jan,10,200,city].
102:[prav,103,2023,city].
```

but these things to be added in runtime

Comment: Could you post the code that you currently have? It's hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **put** function: [Oracle Documentation - HashMap - Put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

So for example, let's say you have an

```
ArrayList<User> aList = new ArrayList<User>();
```

you set this list to whatever you want, then you do

```
map1.put(101, aList);
```

Note: I think what you mean is to create a

```
HashMap<Integer, User>();
```

since your integer key is pointing to only one User, which has multiple attributes (Date, City, etc.). In this case the second argument for put will be a User instead of an ArrayList.

Hope this helps. (Sorry for the bad formatting, that's my first answer)

Answer (score 0):

The code will be as below to add userList to Map

```
   package com.orm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class User {
User(String name, int id, String city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.city = city;
}

String name;
int id;
String city;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
```

}

```
  public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Map<Integer ,ArrayList<User> > userMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<User>>();
     User user1 = new User("Jan", 101, "city");
     User user2 = new User("Prav", 103, "city");
     ArrayList<User>userList = new ArrayList<User>();
     userList.add(user1);
     userList.add(user2);
     userMap.put(1,userList )
        }
```

}

Comment: here  User user1 = new User("Jan", 10, "city");
     User user2 = new User("Prav", 103, "city");
     userList.add(101, user1);
     userList.add(102, user2);    i have to add values dynamically in runtime

Comment: understand that list cannot support key - value structure,only map does

Comment: ya i want to clear you what was my question to you . you are adding userList.add(101, user1);
     userList.add(102, user2); now each time the value of the constructor will be given at run time and the same time key should also increment like userList.add(101, user1);
     userList.add(102, user2);userList.add(103, user4);
     userList.add(104, user4);